# Task.Run still freezing UI

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

So, i'm trying to convert a large byte array into it's base64 encoded variant. But no matter what i try, it seems to freeze up my UI every time it runs.

**This is what i've got currently:**

```
private async void TxtOutput_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string outputText = String.Empty;


        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {

            string[] path = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path[0]);
            txtOutput.Text = await Task.Run(() => {return Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);});
            _ = fileBytes;
            _ = path;

        }
    }
```

So, the line that freezes everything up is:

```
txtOutput.Text = await Task.Run(() => {return Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);});
```

Comment: Did you try to move `File.ReadAllBytes` to the task?

Comment: e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) what is done here

Comment: @Johnny Yea, didn't affect anything.

Comment: Use the asynchronous versions where possible: `await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path[0])`

Comment: Step through the code line by line and see which lines take the longest.

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Forgot to add to my original post. It's the line which converts the byte array to it's Base64 variant. WinForms

Comment: _"the line that freezes everything up is"_ -- please be more specific. The two things most likely in your question to block the UI thread for some time are the program statement just _before_ the line you claim is the problem (the call to `ReadAllBytes()`), and the assignment to the `txtOutput.Text` property. Fact is, if there's a lot of data, _both_ of those may be slow and block the UI thread. If there's not, neither should be a problem. Without a good [mcve] there's no way to provide a good answer.

Comment: Can I ask how you verified that the `Task.Run` line is what is freezing the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so it turns out that my problem was using a textbox for writing the string to instead of a richtextbox. This fixed my problem. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
 File.ReadAllBytes(path[0])
```

Could be a bottle neck you can use async operation for read files
Here is an example how to read file async

```
        public async Task ProcessReadAsync()  
    {  
        string filePath = @"temp2.txt";  

        if (File.Exists(filePath) == false)  
        {  
            Debug.WriteLine("file not found: " + filePath);  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            try  
            {  
                string text = await ReadTextAsync(filePath);  
                Debug.WriteLine(text);  
            }  
            catch (Exception ex)  
            {  
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);  
            }  
        }  
    }  

    private async Task<string> ReadTextAsync(string filePath)  
    {  
        using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,  
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,  
            bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))  
        {  
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  

            byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];  
            int numRead;  
            while ((numRead = await sourceStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)  
            {  
                string text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, numRead);  
                sb.Append(text);  
            }  

            return sb.ToString();  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Running async didn't help. Tried this a while ago. Thanks

Comment: @HarrisonCampbell No I meant you should wrap this code in in Task.Run() method. What .NET framework are you using?

Comment: Yea, i tried that, my bad. Using .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Reading a file is IO bound work. This should never go to a background thread but be async. For this purpose the library already< exposes an async version of this method: [`File.ReadAllBytesAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytesasync?view=netcore-3.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @BionicCode `File.ReadAllBytesAsync` is only available in .NET Core 2.0+

Comment: @BionicCode it is in .NET Core support file async operations.

Comment: If you can't use it then do it properly and use await only. No background thread: `Task<byte[]> task = new Task(File.ReadAllBytes(path[0])); task.Start(); await task;`

Comment: @BionicCode I think you need to try that before you recommend it.

Comment: @BionicCode That still won't compile. But I think what you're trying to do is exactly what Serghei's answer does (execute `ReadAllBytes` in a `Task`).

Comment: @HarrisonCampbell provided you example how to read file async in .NET 4.7 look answer updated

Comment: Sorry but this will compile: `Task<byte[]> task = new Task<byte[]>(() => File.ReadAllBytes(path[0])); task.Start(); await task;` I forgot the parentheses of the lambda. This is different from `Task.Run` as it is simply asynchronous without  wasting a background task for IO operations..

Comment: @BionicCode Nope. Still doesn't compile :) You need `new Task<byte[]>(...`

Comment: Yep you are absolutely right. I should take breath next time :)

Comment: @BionicCode But also read this: [“Task.Factory.StartNew” vs “new Task(…).Start”](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-factory-startnew-vs-new-task-start/) (and note that `Task.Run` is equivalent to `Task.Factory.StartNew`)